# Where in the Pali Canon does it give examples of right livelihood and it's opposite

Tags: pali-canon, reference-request, right-livelihood

A while ago I remember reading part of the Pail Canon where it gave a comprehensive list of professions the Buddha considers **not** right livelihood. It has things like fortune tellers in the list. I remember the list was quite anachronistic in parts but also very interesting and instructive. Can anyone give that reference and perhaps copy in the original text if it isn't too long.

Also is there an equivalent list of professions that would be considered right livelihood in the Pail Canon.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An introduction to [Right Livelihood](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ajivo/) on accesstoinsight references very short definitions of right and wrong livelihood for lay followers. And in fact I've never yet found a detailed description of right and wrong livelihood, beyond these quotes. You can also infer some ethical rules from what the [Sigalovada Sutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigalovada_Sutta) says about Workers; and from RIght Livelihood being on the "ethics" branch of the Eight-fold path.

The "not right livelihood which include things like fortune tellers in the list" might be from here, [The Great Section on Virtue in Samaññaphala Sutta: The Fruits of the Contemplative Life](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html#livelihood) (note that these are said to be 'wrong' for "contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
faith"):

> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
>   faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
>   as: reading marks on the limbs [e.g., palmistry]; reading omens and
>   signs; interpreting celestial events [falling stars, comets];
>   interpreting dreams; reading features of the body [e.g., phrenology];
>   reading marks on cloth gnawed by mice; offering fire oblations,
>   oblations from a ladle, oblations of husks, rice powder, rice grains,
>   ghee, and oil; offering oblations from the mouth; offering
>   blood-sacrifices; making predictions based on the fingertips;
>   geomancy; making predictions for state officials; laying demons in a
>   cemetery; placing spells on spirits; earth-skills [divining water and
>   gems?]; snake-skills, poison-skills, scorpion-skills, rat-skills,
>   bird-skills, crow-skills; predicting life spans; giving protective
>   charms; casting horoscopes — he abstains from wrong livelihood, from
>   "animal" arts such as these.
>
> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
>   faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
>   as: determining lucky and unlucky gems, staffs, garments, swords,
>   arrows, bows, and other weapons; women, men, boys, girls, male slaves,
>   female slaves; elephants, horses, buffaloes, bulls, cows, goats, rams,
>   fowl, quails, lizards, rabbits, tortoises, and other animals — he
>   abstains from wrong livelihood, from "animal" arts such as these.
>
> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
>   faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
>   as [forecasting]: the rulers will march forth; the rulers will not
>   march forth; our rulers will attack, and their rulers will retreat;
>   their rulers will attack, and our rulers will retreat; there will be
>   triumph for our rulers and defeat for their rulers; there will be
>   triumph for their rulers and defeat for our rulers; thus there will be
>   triumph this one, defeat for that one — he abstains from wrong
>   livelihood, from "animal" arts such as these.
>
> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
>   faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
>   as [forecasting]: there will be a lunar eclipse; there will be a solar
>   eclipse; there will be an occultation of [a conjunction of the moon or
>   a planet with] an asterism; the sun and moon will be favorable; the
>   sun and moon will be unfavorable; the asterisms will be favorable; the
>   asterisms will be unfavorable; there will be a meteor shower; there
>   will be a flickering light on the horizon [an aurora?]; there will be
>   an earthquake; there will be thunder coming from dry clouds; there
>   will be a rising, a setting, a darkening, a brightening of the sun,
>   moon, and asterisms; such will be the result of the lunar eclipse ...
>   the rising, setting, darkening, brightening of the sun, moon, and
>   asterisms — he abstains from wrong livelihood, from "animal" arts such
>   as these.
>
> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
>   faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
>   as [forecasting]: there will be abundant rain; there will be a
>   drought; there will be plenty; there will be famine; there will be
>   rest and security; there will be danger; there will be disease; there
>   will be freedom from disease; or they earn their living by accounting,
>   counting, calculation, composing poetry, or teaching hedonistic arts
>   and doctrines [lokāyata] — he abstains from wrong livelihood, from
>   "animal" arts such as these.
>
> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
>   faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
>   as: calculating auspicious dates for marriages — both those in which
>   the bride is brought home and those in which she is sent out;
>   calculating auspicious dates for betrothals and divorces; for
>   collecting debts or making investments and loans; reciting charms to
>   make people attractive or unattractive; curing women who have
>   undergone miscarriages or abortions; reciting spells to bind a man's
>   tongue, to paralyze his jaws, to make him lose control over his hands,
>   or to bring on deafness; getting oracular answers to questions
>   addressed to a spirit in a mirror, in a young girl, or to a spirit
>   medium; worshipping the sun, worshipping the Great Brahmā, bringing
>   forth flames from the mouth, invoking the goddess of luck — he
>   abstains from wrong livelihood, from "animal" arts such as these.
>
> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
>   faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
>   as: promising gifts to deities in return for favors; fulfilling such
>   promises; demonology; reciting spells in earth houses [see earth
>   skills, above]; inducing virility and impotence; preparing sites for
>   construction; consecrating sites for construction; giving ceremonial
>   mouthwashes and ceremonial baths; offering sacrificial fires;
>   administering emetics, purges, purges from above, purges from below,
>   head-purges; ear-oil, eye-drops, treatments through the nose,
>   ointments, and counter-ointments; practicing eye-surgery [or:
>   extractive surgery], general surgery, pediatrics; administering
>   root-medicines and binding medicinal herbs — he abstains from wrong
>   livelihood, from "animal" arts such as these. This, too, is part of
>   his virtue."
>
> "A monk thus consummate in virtue sees no danger anywhere from his
>   restraint through virtue. Just as a head-anointed noble warrior king
>   who has defeated his enemies sees no danger anywhere from his enemies,
>   in the same way the monk thus consummate in virtue sees no danger
>   anywhere from his restraint through virtue. Endowed with this noble
>   aggregate of virtue, he is inwardly sensitive to the pleasure of being
>   blameless. This is how a monk is consummate in virtue.

Answer (score 2):

The five types of wrong livelihood:

1. Weapons dealing
2. Human trafficking (slavery, prostitution)
3. Intoxiciant dealing
4. Poison dealing
5. Any work dealing with meat
   -- AN 5.177

Wrong Action in One's Livelihood

1. Scheming
2. Persuading
3. Hinting
4. Belittling
5. Pursuing gain with gain

-- MN 117

Wrong Livelihood for Contemplatives

1. reading marks on the limbs [like palmistry]
2. reading omens and signs
3. interpreting celestial events
4. interpreting dreams;
5. reading marks on the body
6. reading marks on cloth gnawed by mice
7. offering fire oblations
8. oblations from a ladle, oblations of husks, rice powder, rice grains, ghee, and oil
9. offering oblations from the mouth
10. offering blood-sacrifices
11. making predictions based on the fingertips
12. geomancy
13. laying demons in a cemetery
14. placing spells on spirits
15. reciting house-protection charms
16. snake charming, poison-lore, scorpion-lore, rat-lore, bird-lore, crow-lore
17. fortune-telling based on visions
18. giving protective charms
19. interpreting the calls of birds and animals ... [The list goes on and on]

-- DN 2

Comment: http://www.buddha-vacana.org/articles/mn117-counterfeit.html claims that section of MN 117 is "tampered with material from the Abhidhamma" and is taken from a list in AN 5.83 of things which would be disagreeable endowments in a bikkhu.